# Selecting groups name of current_user

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-roles

I use the following command to check the groups or roles of a user in a PostgreSQL database,

```
select rolname from pg_authid where pg_has_role('some_username', rolname, 'member');
```

As seen, I have to manually type the user name in above query, like `'some_username'` above.

Is there a way I can query it for the current_user, I mean for the user who is curently connected with the database. Something like command below,

```
select rolname from pg_authid where pg_has_role(current_user, rolname, 'member');
```

This command doesn't work properly. It returns complete `rolname` column from `pg_authid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `pg_authid` you need to be superuser, and therefor `current_user` will be the superuser and that one has all the roles.

To get that information when you are logged in with a non-superuser, use `pg_roles`

[Quote from the manual for `pg_roles`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-roles.html)

> This is simply a publicly readable view of pg_authid that blanks out the password field.

```
select rolname 
from pg_roles 
where pg_has_role(current_user, rolname, 'member');
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working great. You are always a lifesaver regarding SQL :)